# When are two artifacts considered equal?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Are two artifacts considered the same for dependency resolution if they have two different values for their respective groups? For example, will

- **com**.example:*artifact*

and

- **org**.example:*artifact*

resolve to the same version of *artifact* on my classpath (where gradle by default will choose the latest)? Or will I get two copies of *artifact* (because Gradle considers the artifacts different and puts both on the classpath)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle considers dependencies unique if they have matching group, name and version. In your example, those two dependencies would **not** be considered the same since they have different groups, and would therefore be duplicated. If you know in advance that such a duplication exists, you can declare a [module replacement](http://www.gradle.org/docs/2.2/release-notes#declaring-module-replacements).

```
dependencies {
  modules {
    module("com.example:artifact") {
      replacedBy("org.example:artifact")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "... if they have matching group, name, and **version**" but I thought that two dependencies with the same name and group but different versions will automatically be resolved to the latest version (by default).

Comment: I have verified [this answer is correct](https://github.com/dcow/dependency-conflict). Thanks.